# window.open not working inside string

Tags: javascript

I want to open window using window.open method But I want to use this function inside a string function. I have write some code but it is not working.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var str= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open("http://www.google.com","mywin","height=1000, width=500")">google</a>'
$('body').append(str)
})</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're putting quotes within quotes (`'"Hello, "World!""'`). You need to [escape them](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470891/Web-Developer-Tutorial-Escape-Characters.htm) using a backslash (`\`). Change:

```
onclick="window.open("...", "...", "...")"
```

To:

```
onclick="window.open(\"...\", \"...\", \"...\")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quotes mismatched.. Add backslash(/)

```
var str= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open(\"http://www.google.com","mywin","height=1000, width=500\")">google</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add escape characters to the " within the string...

```
var str= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open(\"http://www.google.com\",\"mywin\","height=1000, width=500\")">google</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are using `"` inside another `"`, so you need to use escape character for that `\`

here is the updated code-

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var str= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open(\"http://www.google.com\",\"mywin\",\"height=1000, width=500\")">google</a>'
$('body').append(str)
})</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `"` inside `onclick=".."` using `\'`

```
$(function(){
    var str= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open(\'http://www.google.com\',\'mywin\',\'height=1000, width=500\')">google</a>'
    $('body').append(str)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jWux2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use another function

```
var clickFunc=function () {window.open("http://www.google.com","mywin","height=1000, width=500")};
var str= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="clickFunc()">google</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"window.open('http://www.google.com','mywin','height=1000, width=500')\">google</a>";
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please add some explanation on where the error actually was and what you did to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a single quote when calling a function inside double quotes. You may do something like:

```
onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com')"
```